# Creating a Certificate Signing Request using smartcard in C++

Tags: c++, smartcard, pkcs#11, csr

I have a smart card and it has own special pkcs11 library. I examine gnutls, openssl but they use own generated private key. How can I generate csr(pkcs10) using smartcard in C++?

Comment: If you are looking to generate CSR and Download Certificate from web application, please refer stackoverflow.com/a/68556286/9659885 SignerDigital Browser Extension for Linux is written native in c++ which also has this feature.

Answer (score 1):

You don't generate a CSR using smartcard -- you generate a keypair, which is then used to create a CSR. I know that our [SecureBlackbox](https://www.eldos.com/sbb/desc-pki.php) product lets one do this. Or you can call PKCS#11 library to generate a key pair, then use [PKCS#11 extension to OpenSSL](https://github.com/OpenSC/engine_pkcs11) to create a CSR.

Comment: I want to use private key inside the smartcard to create a CSR with OpenSSL. I use AKIS smartcard and OpenSSL can't use this smart card as engine. When I typed "p11tool --provider /usr/lib/libakisp11.so --list-privkeys --login", I encountered error like invalid arguments(doesn't load library). So I'm searching another ways of creating CSR with private key inside the smart card.

Comment: @omeryildiz if the PKCS#11 driver doesn't work for you, the first thing to do is investigate, why - it should work. You probably need to contact the vendor for support. In any case, without a driver there can be no [other] way to deal with the hardware device.